# hive logger always shows INFO

Tags: hadoop, logging, configuration, hive

Sorry for this duplicated post. But I really did not find a solution for this...

I am using hive-0.9.0 binary version on my macbook pro. The problem is for every step, the query returns numerous log for INFO and WARNING. First it does not help for me, a beginner because unclear. Second, I am not sure it may affect speed?

I did some research and followed the solutions given by those people. What I did are as follow:

1. Modify $HADOOP_CONF/log4j.properties: change "hadoop.root.logger=INFO,console" to "hadoop.root.logger=ERROR"
2. Modify $HIVE_CONF/hive-exec-log4j.properties: change "hive.root.logger=INFO,FA" to "hive.root.logger=ERROR"; change "log4j.threshhold=WARN" to "log4j.threshhold=ERROR"
3. Do similar thing of 2. in $HIVE_CONF/hive-log4j.properties
4. check some line like "log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation=WARN" in $HADOOP_CONF and uncomment it. But I did not find anything similar to this line.

None of them works. Can somebody help me? Many thanks!!!

Comment: I am still waiting for an answer......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your HADOOP_OPTS environment variable (usually set in $HADOOP_CONF_DIR/hadoop-env.sh.

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Dhadoop.root.logger=ERROR $HADOOP_OPTS"
```